# RequestFactoryServlet unexpected error - Cannot cast Boolean to String

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, java-7, requestfactory

I am trying to switch my application to java-7 but when I use RequestFactory to load my object from appengine I receive the following error:

```
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet doPost: Unexpected error
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Boolean to java.lang.String
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3062)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.vm.impl.BeanPropertyContext.set(BeanPropertyContext.java:44)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.Resolver$PropertyResolver.visitValueProperty(Resolver.java:155)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.vm.impl.ProxyAutoBean.traverseProperties(ProxyAutoBean.java:289)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.traverse(AbstractAutoBean.java:166)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.accept(AbstractAutoBean.java:101)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.Resolver.resolveClientValue(Resolver.java:414)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.processInvocationMessages(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:491)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:233)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:135)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.doPost(RequestFactoryServlet.java:133)
```

With java-6 everything is working normally. This situation only occurs with java-7 and only on the appengine. There is no problem when I am using java-7 with development mode. Any ideas what can be causing this issue ?

Comment: Could it be that you have 2 setters with the same name, one taking a `String` and the other a `Boolean` or `boolean`?

Comment: it is one setter for Boolean

Comment: Looking at the code for `BeanPropertyContext`, it looks like a type mismatch between the getter and the setter (getter of type `String`, setter of type `Boolean`).

Comment: I just had this error and found that the server class had a "hasValue" and "getValue", one which returned a boolean and one which returned a String. I removed the hasValue and it worked. Edit: Also, the error wouldn't occur in superdev mode. It only errored on a full build deploy.